# React styled components not displaying on screen

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, web-applications, styled-components

I am creating a web application using React and Ruby on Rails but my style components are not showing up. It worked fine when I had the first two style components but after making the third nothing works even when I removed the third component. After running rails my screen is now completely blank.

This is my code

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Section = styled.section`

   background-color: #d74234
   min-height: 550px;
   padding: 100px 0;
   color: #fff;
`;

const Header = styled.h1`

   color: #fff;
   font-weight: 700;
   font-size: 40px;
   line-height: 52px
`;

const Subhead = styled.p`

   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: 500;
`;
const Button = styled.a`

   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight: bold;
   cursor: pointer;
   border-radius: 0;
   background: #fff;
   color: #333 !important;
   padding: 10px 20px;
   font-size: 18px;
   width: 100%;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #473228,
     -6px 6px #ef5f17,
     -6px 6px 0px 3px #473228;
`;

const Jumbotron = () => {
    return (
      <Section className="home-section--1">
          <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                  <div className="col col-sm-12 col-md-5">
                      <div className="pt-4 mt-4">
                          <Header>Curiosity Voyage!</Header>
                          <Subhead>Where all your random questions are answered</Subhead>
                          <div className = "cta-wrapper">
                            <Button className= "btn fancy-btn">Explore</Button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col col-sm-12 col-md-7">
                      <div className="pt-4 mt-4 text-center">

                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </Section>
    )
}

export default Jumbotron
```

I tried two solutions and neither worked, I included a backtick just before the semi-colons and also tried adding curly braces just before the styling.

I took a look at some info on Visual Studio and the styled-components within the section tag and got this message

const Button: 'StyledComponent<"a", any, {}, never>
and all of the tags have the same message, so it seems like it's not reading the styled-components within the Jumbtron. Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you provide more information, add code of your components, show how you added styles.
Also do you have any errors in browser console? maybe you can check some error logs

Comment: Sorry, it took awhile, I had to figure out how to embed the code properly, I know it's not much help without it.

Comment: you have closed branch `}` in your code `line-height: 52px; }`, could you try remove it? you have it in ` Subhead ` and `Button `

Comment: Hey, I removed them now and still no changes have been made. The app is still a blank page.

Comment: What about error? do you see anywhere errors (browser console, terminal, errors.log) if you have blank page it means that you have syntax error

Comment: No errors come up anywhere, the screen is just blank.

Comment: The app works now, for some reason the Jumbotron component that links the css wasn't working. I fiddled with it a bit and now it works. The css itself was fine, checking the console gave me a clear idea of what to look for. So, thank you @Oleksandr